# Confused on outlet and Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have 3 routes so far:

```
index
get-started
lets-design
```

From router.js:

```
  this.route('get-started');
  this.route('lets-design');
```

From index I do:

```
  {{#link-to 'get-started' class="btn btn-primary"}}Get started{{/link-to}}
```

Which then takes me to a fresh page of get started. Great.

From get-started I do:

```
  {{#link-to 'lets-design' class="btn btn-primary"}}Get started!{{/link-to}}
```

Which takes me to the text in lets-design "let's design" but it's on top of "get started" text which was in that template.

How do I get the transition to only show content from the let's design template? Why did it add it on top of the get-started page? E.g, it appended the content into the view, I just wanted a fresh transition like the initial click from index.

```
generated -> controller:get-started Object {fullName: "controller:get-started"} ember.js:3231
Rendering get-started with default view <appkit@view:default::ember334> Object {fullName: "view:get-started"} ember.js:3231
Transitioned into 'get-started' ember.js:3231
generated -> controller:lets-design Object {fullName: "controller:lets-design"} ember.js:3231
Rendering lets-design with default view <appkit@view:default::ember357> Object {fullName: "view:lets-design"} ember.js:3231
Transitioned into 'lets-design' ember.js:3231
```

Also when I go back to index from let's design, the content is duplicated 3 times. Why is this?

Repo: https://github.com/ecl1pse/ember-transition-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad html (mismatched tags in your templates) is usually the cause of this.  In your case at the end of your get-started you have an opening ul tag, but it has no matching closing tag.

https://github.com/ecl1pse/ember-transition-help/blob/master/app/templates/get-started.hbs#L17